# Does hbase 0.94.18 supports for secondary indexes?

Tags: hbase, secondary-indexes

I'm currently try to experience hbase to develop a hbase connector for a given project. so that I need to develop secondary indexing for that. so that I just need to know does hbase 0.94.18 supports for secondary indexes using coprocessors. Can somebody give me a help to do that ? because I'm really new to hbase and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase itself doesn't support secondary index. But you can refer to [this](https://github.com/Huawei-Hadoop/hindex) Huawei add secondary index for HBase.